# How to override parameter in sublass of @MappedSuperclass

Tags: java, hibernate, mappedsuperclass

I have a MappedSuperclass

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class A{
    .
    .
    .
    @Column(name="something")
    public getSomething(){..};
    public setSomething(){..};
}
```

I want to override the `something` in a subclass

```
@Entity
public class B{
    @Override
    public getSomething(){..};
}
```

but getting `Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Duplicate property mapping of data found` Exception

I tried different things like "@AttributeOverride" annotation, but it didn't help.

The only solution i know is to make `something` Transient in the mappedSuperclass. But i don't want that it will be transient here (because there is another subclasses that don't want to override `something` but want that it will be transient)

Answer (score 3):

Two solutions occur to me: one is to maybe break this SuperClass up and use Emmbeddeds to create the hierarchy you want.  If you want to stick with this approach though, I think you need to override using [@AttributeOverride](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/AttributeOverride.html) both the property and the method like this in the subclass:

```
@Entity
public class B {

    @AttributeOverride(name = "fred", column = @Column(name = "FRED"))
    private Integer fred;

    @Override
    public Integer getFred() {return fred;}
}
```